# jslint Bad property name '$wrapper'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

Well for the first time today I seem to have asked a question that isn't immediately highlighted as a duplicate!

I'm working my way through alot of the error messages that JSLint is giving me and trying to solve them.

I've got several that are telling me I have bad property names, if you're curious they are :

- $wrapper
- $el
- $slider
- $feedbackWrapper
- $feedback
- $labelWrapper
- $labels

I have a feeling it's due to the $ sign at the start but why would that be a problem? as far as I was aware it's quite common practice to cache jQuery objects using $ at the start of the variable name.

Anyway I'd naturally prefer to correct this error with something that conforms to a good standard however if it's just one of those things that people can live with, is there a way of telling jslint to ignore these?

Thanks

EDIT: I can't share the whole class since it's being used in a project by the company I work for but here is the render function where alot of these properties are set.

```
render: function () {
    TextImage.prototype.render.call(this);

    var $slider = this.$wrapper.find('.in-panel');
    this.$wrapper = this.$el.find('.panel');

    this.$labelWrapper = this.$wrapper.find('.in-panel');

    this.$feedbackWrapper = this.$wrapper.find('.text');
    this.$feedback = this.$feedbackWrapper.find('.feedback');
    this.$feedbackWrapper.addClass("hidden");

    this.itemIndex = -1;
    this.createSlider($slider);

},
```

Comment: Could you share the script so we can see what your working with?

Comment: updated my original thread

Comment: not sure if bumping threads is acceptable here but if anyone can help I'm still really curious about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code in JSlint you will see, it does not like properties that start with $, _ and probably other non letter symbols.

The ones I found: 
    it does not like properties that CONTAIN $ (it likes variables though)
    it does not like properties that start with _ though they can contain 
I encourage you to do a more extensive search.
If you copy paste these you will see some examples of when it complains

```
var a = 23;
var $b = 24;
var c = {};
c.$a = 4;
c.a$t = 5;
c.c_a = 6;
c._a = 53;
c._d = 25;
c.this = 32;
c.window = 55;
```